# Balanced-Payments Try Catch response

Tags: try-catch, balanced-payments

I've attempting to learn how to set up credit card payments and using a Balanced Payments test marketplace.   I haven't ever set up a try catch statement before and I am having some trouble with processing the response.

Here is my controller try/catch statement:

```
try{
        $card->debits->create(array(
        "amount" => $amount,
        "appears_on_statement_as" => "test",
        "description" => $invoiceId,
        "order" => $order,
        ));

        } catch (Balanced\Errors\Declined $e) {
            $this->arrResponse['status'] = $e->getMessage();
            return Response::json($this->arrResponse);
        }
        $invoice->save();

         // send email function...
         //redirect
         $this->arrResponse['status'] = SUCCESS;
            return Response::json($this->arrResponse);
```

I can see the error on chrome developer tools, but I can't make it appear on my view.

Chrome dev tools 500 internal server error statement:

```
error: {type: "Balanced\Errors\Declined", message: "",…}
file:  "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testcc/vendor/balanced/balanced/src/Balanced/Errors/Error.php"
line: 42
message: ""
type: "Balanced\Errors\Declined
```

processpayment.js file:

```
 jQuery.post(baseURL+'/processPayment', {
            uri: fundingInstrument.href,
            amount: amount,
            invoiceId: invoiceId,
        }, function(r) {
            // backend response
            if (r.status === 200) {
                $('#msgSection').empty().removeClass('alert-error alert-success').addClass('alert-success').text(' payment has been received').show();

            } else {
                // failure from backend
                $('#msgSection').empty().removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-warning').text('error').show();
            }
        });
```

When test card is processed successfully, everything works and success message appears on my view.  However, when I use a test card that is declined, no message is sent to my view.   Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to check balanced-php client testsuite to see how they use try catch block from [here](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/tests/Balanced/SuiteTest.php)

so your code would be like.

```
  try{
       $card->debits->create(array(
          "amount" => $amount,
          "appears_on_statement_as" => "test",
          "description" => $invoiceId,
          "order" => $order,
        ));

  } catch (Balanced\Errors\Declined $e) {
         $this->arrResponse['status'] = $e->category_code;
         return Response::json($this->arrResponse);
  }
  $invoice->save();

  // send email function...
  //redirect
  $this->arrResponse['status'] = SUCCESS;
  return Response::json($this->arrResponse);
```

`$e->category_code` will be either `funding-destination-declined` or `authorization-failed` or `card-declined`